# How to register middleware in routes file to be handled after request is processed

Tags: laravel, laravel-9, laravel-middleware

I have a login route that makes sure that a user is verified before logging in like so.

```php
Route::post('/login', [AuthController::class, 'login'])->middleware('userIsVerified');
```

However in the case of the user entering a wrong password, it passes through the middleware first and then returns that the user is not verified in case of the user is not verified.

How to tweak this middleware to make it run after the request is processed by the controller?

Here is the middleware code:

```php
class UserIsVerified
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (auth()->user()) {
            $userIsVerified = auth()->user()->verified;
        } else {
            $user = Client::where('phone', $request->phone)->first();
            if (!$user)
                return response(['message' => 'User doesnt exist.'], Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
            $userIsVerified = $user->verified;
        }
        if (!! $userIsVerified)
            return $next($request);
        else
            return response(['message' => 'User is not verified.'], Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you exactly want to achieve if the user is not verified in this situation?

Comment: @Aless55 If for instance the password is incorrect and the user does exist, it should return that the password you entered is incorrect, yet it returns that the user is not verified

Comment: So you can exclude the login route from this middleware and perform the check in your auth controller

Comment: is this middleware used in more than one place? seems like it should just be part of the login functionality

Comment: Yes it is actually used alongside the Authenticated middleware in validating subsequent requests

Answer (score 0):

Laravel middleware has one more method callled `terminate()`, this method apply after the response. Its called terminable middleware.

[Read More About terminate](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/middleware#terminable-middleware)